# Find out how to use a python function in a C module

Tags: python, c

I want to use the project https://github.com/klon/ucrdtw so I downloaded it, build it and installed it into my conda environment with the the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/klon/ucrdtw.git
cd ucrdtw
source activate mycondaenvironment
make
python setup.py install
```

The install process put the files

```
_ucrdtw.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
ucrdtw-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
```

into my conda `site-packages` directory.

There exists a very small readme, but I have no idea what parameters are available and how I am supposed to use them. How can I find that out?

Comment: Why the close vote? How can I improve the question?

Comment: Use the source luke!  https://github.com/klon/ucrdtw/blob/master/src/_ucrdtw.c

Comment: @jq170727: Thanks, I did not know which file would be the entry point. I will try to understand it. Unfortunately I am not fluent in C.

Comment: It's a pretty small module.  There's only one method `ucrdtw` which expects arguments [PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOd|O", &data_obj, &query_obj, &warp_width, &verbose_obj)](https://github.com/klon/ucrdtw/blob/master/src/_ucrdtw.c#L64).  The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html) indicate that the args are parsed as (object, object, double and an optional object).